# Class - User Defined Smart Array with dynamic size

Tags: c++, arrays, class, memory-management, operator-overloading

I am writing the following array (class) that increases the size when index of this array is bigger than size of this array. **I know about vectors but it has to be array**. The Code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Array {

public:
Array():_array(new float[0]), _size(0){};
~Array() {delete[] _array;}
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&,const Array&);
float& operator[] (int index) 
{
  if(index>=_size)
  {
    float* NewArray=new float[index+1];
    for(int i=0;i<_size;++i) NewArray[i]=_array[i];
    for(int i=_size;i<index+1;++i) NewArray[i]=0; 
    delete[] _array;
    _array=NewArray;
    _size=index+1;
  }
  return _array[index];
}

private:
  float *_array; // pointer to array
  int _size; // current size of array
};

ostream &operator << ( ostream &out,  const Array& obj) // overloading operator<< to easily print array
{
  cout << "Array:\n\n";
  for (int i=0;i<obj._size;++i) 
  {
    cout << obj._array[i];
    if(i+1!=obj._size) cout << ", "; 
  }
  cout << ".\n";
  return out;
}

int main()
{
  Array CustomArray;
  CustomArray[2] = CustomArray[1] = CustomArray[0] = 3.14; // **here is the problem**
  cout << CustomArray << endl;
}
```

Everything is ok, 0 warnings , 0 valgrind errors, output :

```
3.14, 3.14, 3.14.
```

BUT **i have** to write this code ( in main ) this way :

```
CustomArray[0] = CustomArray[1] = CustomArray[2] = 3.14;
```

and now it's 3 valgrind errors:
Address (some_address) is 4 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd,

and output looks like that : `0, 0, 3.14.`

unfortunately i have to write this code to work the second way 
( `CustomArray[0] = CustomArray[1] = CustomArray[2] = 3.14;` )
Can you guys help ? Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that `CustomArray[1]` invalidates all previous references and pointers to data because it is reallocated. What you may do is a return an `ArrayAccess` that holds the index and doesn't hold a reference but accesses the original array everytime.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think even `std::vector` could cope with that if one of those `operator[]` calls causes a reallocation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resolve this through the use of a proxy type that holds a reference to the `Array` object and the index passed to your `operator[]`.  This proxy type will be implicitly convertible to `float` and be assignable from `float`, making accesses (mostly<sup>1</sup>) transparent.

We also violate the rule of three in this case and implement the copy-assignment operator to assign the value of one array element to another so that `foo[0] = foo[1]` works as expected.

We need to make the following changes:

1. Rename the existing `operator[]` and make it private; it will only be used by the proxy type.
2. Create a new `operator[]` that returns a value of the proxy type.
3. Write the proxy type.

Change 1, inside of `Array`'s definition:

```
friend class ArrayElement; // So that ArrayElement can use access()
private:
float& access(int index) 
{
  if(index>=_size)
  {
    float* NewArray=new float[index+1];
    for(int i=0;i<_size;++i) NewArray[i]=_array[i];
    for(int i=_size;i<index+1;++i) NewArray[i]=0; 
    delete[] _array;
    _array=NewArray;
    _size=index+1;
  }
  return _array[index];
}
```

Change 2:

```
// Inside of Array
public:
    ArrayElement operator[](int index);

// Implementation outside of Array
ArrayElement Array::operator[](int index) {
    return ArrayElement(*this, index);
}
```

Change 3:

```
class ArrayElement
{
    friend class Array; // So that Array can use our private constructor

private:
    ArrayElement(Array & array, int index) : array(array), index(index) { }

public:
    // Allows "foo[1] = 2"
    ArrayElement const & operator=(float v) const {
        array.access(index) = v;
        return *this;
    }

    // Violation of the rule of three, but it makes sense in this case.
    // Allows "foo[1] = foo[2]"
    ArrayElement const & operator=(ArrayElement const & other) const {
        array.access(index) = other;
        return *this;
    }

    // Allows "float x = foo[1]"
    operator float() const {
        return array.access(index);
    }

private:
    Array & array;
    int index;
};
```

(Minor final change, you need to forward declare `ArrayElement` before the definition of `Array`.)

[See this working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4803af0b937fe3f).

---

<sup>1</sup> One of the caveats of this approach is using type-inference (`auto` in C++11) on array accesses:

```
auto x = an_array[1];
```

Now `x` is an `ArrayElement` instead of a `float` and its value will be observed to change when `an_array[1]` changes.  Attempting to assign a different float value to `x` will change the value in `an_array[1]` as well, since `x` is just a proxy to that value.

Contrast this to the general behavior of `std::vector` where `auto x = a_vector[0]` will result in `x` being the element type of the vector, and therefore will hold an independent copy of the value stored in the vector.

Note, however, that the `std::vector<bool>` specialization follows exactly the approach I've given here (returning a proxy object) and so [it does have the same `auto` caveat](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a09025200cd95720)!  You could take that as a blessing on this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector`, directly or indirectly. Your statement

> I know about vectors but it has to be array.

doesn't make sense. `std::vector` is guaranteed to have contiguous storage, which is probably what you mean by "array". For an instance `v`, you could always use the expression `&v[0]` to obtain the base address of the array, and, starting from C++11 the easier to read `v.data()` will work as well. This means you can use a `vector` for any function call that requires an array "C-style" as pointer and size, e.g. `qsort`.

If you cannot do without the automatic resize in `Array::operator []`, then make a class wrapper as you have done, but use `std::vector` *internally*. This is much simpler and safer. Particularily, your code has quadratic worst case performance, e.g. the following will be very very slow:

```
Array CustomArray;
for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
     CustomArray[i] = i;
```

`std::vector` is designed to *not* have this problem.

The other problem you mentioned, with the reference invalidation, could be solved easily by using `std::deque` instead, however `deque` does not have contiguous storage. Therefore, with `std::vector`, you would still have to use a proxy as described by cdhowie. However, I must confess I do not quite understand why the syntax has to be like that, or what's wrong with calling `std::vector<float>::resize()` manually.